# CSS object-fit stretching image

Tags: html, css

I have a regular `img` tag with `src` pointing to an image

on large/tall images object-fit is stretching images instead of showing them as they should.

Using contain resolves the issue but this is not the desired effect.

Is there any misconfiguration from my side ? or there is a css issue here ? I would appreciate if someone knows a solution.

The HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
  <div>
   <img src="image-url" class="image" >
   <div>
    <h2>title</h2>
    <p>description</p>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The CSS

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to post more of your code in order to see the issue you're having? According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit), `object fit: cover;` will fill the entire containing box, while maintaining aspect ratio. Any part of the image that falls outside of its containing element will be clipped.

Comment: nothing special in the code just like this <img src="image-url" class="class-name"> then i applied these css in the description, I am using ReactJS though im not sure this has to do with this.

Comment: @karolus i have updated to show the code

Comment: OK—one more question—what are the image dimensions?

Comment: A few screenshots would be helpful, but I suspect that perhaps you don't want `cover`, but want either `contains` or `scale-down`